# Web Control CRUD operations on Telerik RadGrid using LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, webforms, telerik-grid, radgrid

i have a hierarchical radGrid where the user clicks a row on the detail table to edit its data in a web control.

how do i update the grid data using linq to sql?

Answer (score 0):

i accomplished this task by following the example provided by telerik and modifying it as follows:

```
protected void RadGridProductionOrders_UpdateCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        UserControl userControl = (UserControl)e.Item.FindControl(GridEditFormItem.EditFormUserControlID);
        ProductionOrderDetail productionOrderDetail = new ProductionOrderDetail();
        ProductionDataContext db = new ProductionDataContext();

        productionOrderDetail = (from p in db.ProductionOrderDetails
                                 where p.orderNo == editedItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[editedItem.ItemIndex]["orderNo"]
                                    && p.itemCode == editedItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[editedItem.ItemIndex]["itemCode"]
                                 select p).Single();

        productionOrderDetail.qty = int.Parse((userControl.FindControl("TextBoxQty") as TextBox).Text);

        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Label lblError = new Label();

            lblError.Text = "Unable to update Production Order data. Reason: " + ex.Message;
            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            RadGridProductionOrders.Controls.Add(lblError);

            e.Canceled = true;
        }
}
```

after this code completes the grid is updated with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can examine the demo (very simple and clear) on Telerik's website:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/programaticlinqupdates/defaultcs.aspx